# Accessible method for indicating primary actions vs secondary

Tags: html, accessibility

I am currently going through the a11y for my site and have run across a situation that I'm not able to find any advice on how to handle, or if I should.

I have 2 links that appear in the homepage banner, one of which is the primary action, and the other is a secondary action. I am unsure how to go about indicating this difference with (for example) ARIA properties.

Run this snippet for an idea of the styling I'm using to indicate this relationship to sighted users.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.btn_prime {
  background: green;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  color: white;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="#contact" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
<a href="#register" class="btn btn_prime">Sign Up</a>
```

The current markup is not giving a screen reader any indication that one link is any more relevent than the other and simply reads them sequentially with equal billing. My instinct is that this is providing more information/guidence to sighted users and leaving important information unspoken.

So my question is, *should* I pass this information to screen readers to indicate which button is larger/more important, and if so *how* do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

DOM order signifies importance to screen readers.

If you think that you can place the signup button before the contact button then that is your solution for importance / significance. (but don't then change the order they appear visually using CSS as you will then break logical focus order.)

This is a non-issue, screen reader users will be used to scanning through lists of links to familiarise themselves with a page.

A screen reader user will tend to loop through headings, sections, links etc. on a page until they understand the layout and what information is available to them (or until they find what they are looking for).

Because of this they will likely find your signup link no issue.

Additionally if you had the links in an unordered list (which I assume you do if these are part of navigation?) you benefit from having the sign-up last due to something called "[the Serial position effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial-position_effect)". If there are only these two options in your banner then ignore this point.

> Serial-position effect is the tendency of a person to recall the first and last items in a series best

If you really want to give the best chance of a screen reader user getting to your Call To Action then it should sit in it's own `<section>` with a suitable `<h2>` (or appropriate heading level).

But that probably would mean a redesign of the page for that.

### Proposed solution

Just swap the two options around. If the primary action is to signup then why would you not put that first for **everybody**.

Sighted people read in an "F" pattern. Therefore the closer to the top and left your CTA is, the more likely it is to get noticed and therefore clicked.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.btn_prime {
  background: green;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  color: white;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="#register" class="btn btn_prime">Sign Up</a>
<a href="#contact" class="btn">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. To provide a little more context my surrounding html looks like: `<section> <h1>...<h1/> <p>...</p> <div> <a>Contact</a><a>Signup</a> </div> </section>`

Comment: Then I see no reason why you can't swap the order, especially if the buttons are stacked as they are in your example fiddle. As I said this would probably be better for everyone anyway as your Call To Action should be above "contact us".